# Edge in a convex polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, discrete-mathematics, optimization

I want to show that a convex polytope $A$ that is an intersection of half-spaces contains an edge if $ A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n|Ax=0 \wedge x \ge 0\}$, where x greater equal 0 means, that all components are greater equal zero.

My proof was to say that 0 is an edge since all convex combinations of vectors that are not the zero vector will give a vector different from zero.

Now I was wondering whether this result is true, if A is not defined the way it was in this excercise but as $ A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n|Ax=b \wedge x \ge 0\}$ for b being an arbitrary vector? Does anybody of you know this?

Comment: An edge is the convex hull of two distinct vertices of the polytope.

Comment: I understand neither "0 is an edge" nor "all convex combinations of vectors that are not the zero vector will give a vector different from zero."  Concerning the former, note that an edge never consists of just one point.  Concerning the second, there are plenty of counterexamples, even in $\mathbb R^1$, where $0$ is a convex combination of $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: but -1 is not an element of $P$. What do you mean, an edge never consists of just one point? I thought an edge is always exactly one point.

Comment: @Lipschitz, check the "face lattice" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope. The faces are ranked by dimension: extreme vertices (points) are 0-dim. Edges are 1-dim.